# Web services issue on POST method

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, post, ios8

I am struggled on web services POST method,i used one services in android  and iOS.In the android it's working fine ,but iOS the response didn't come the correct format.Here i am using iOS Code:

```
 Label.text=@"Bangalore";
    NSLog(@"text=%@",Label.text);

   NSString *myRequestString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"city=%@",Label.text];
     NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ myRequestString UTF8String ] length: [ myRequestString length ] ];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString:@"http://****************.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  //  [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
   [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSError* error;
    NSMutableArray* result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData
                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                               error:&error];
    NSLog(@"sss=%@",result);
```

Here i am getting the response like this,

```
sss={
    Bangalore =     (
                {
            Price = 384;
            date = "01-12-2014";
        },
                {
            Price = 384;
            date = "02-12-2014";
        },
                {
            Price = 384;
            date = "03-12-2014";
        },
                {
            Price = 374;
            date = "08-12-2014";
        },
                {
            Price = 374;
            date = "09-12-2014";
        },

                {
            Price = 365;
            date = "13-12-2014";
        },
                {
            Price = 365;
            date = "14-12-2014";
        },

                {
            Price = 369;
            date = "18-12-2014";
        }
    );
}
```

In android same services i get the correct response but iOS i am facing this issue can please how can it solve?and any mistakes on my code? Thank you@

Comment: What is your desired JSON Response?

Comment: From last one i don't want ); this field.@Naeem

Comment: I required only open parentheses

Comment: Try NSDictionary instead of NSMutable Array

Comment: I tried to NSDictionary also,i get the same problem.

Comment: @Rob but this format not JSON format and its not possible to parse the keys

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",result); Try this. Your Response is Right.

Comment: what the problem u faced...

Comment: @iOS2340 BTW, unrelated to your original question, when you get this issue behind you, you really should change this code to use `sendAsynchronousRequest` (or other asynchronous method). One never wants to perform synchronous requests on the main thread in iOS.

Comment: FYI, the initialization of `myRequestData` is not right: It should be `NSData *myRequestData = [myRequestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You received valid JSON, but then successfully parsed it into a dictionary with an array of dictionaries using `NSJSONSerialization`. Don't worry that the `NSLog` of `result` doesn't look like JSON. It's not supposed to.

If you really want to see the original JSON, you can:

```
NSLog(@"Original JSON = ", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

That will look like what you expected (and we knew it would, because otherwise the JSON parsing would have failed). But don't worry about this original JSON. Just use `result`.

Note, though, `result` is a `NSDictionary`, not a `NSArray` (nor a `NSMutableArray`). So you should define it as such.

You can now use `result`:

```
NSArray *bangalore = result[@"Bangalore"];
NSDictionary *priceObject = bangalore[0];
NSString *price = priceObject[@"Price"]; // might be NSNumber, depends on whether JSON had quotes around the price or not
NSString *date = priceObject[@"date"];
```

Comment: Rob its working fine but i want total count,not bangalore[0],

Comment: Of course, navigate the dictionary and array of objects as you see fit. You wouldn't hardcode a `bangalore` variable name, either. Lol. I was just illustrating that you were dealing with dictionary with array of dictionaries and trying to encourage you to not be dissuaded simply because the `NSLog` or `result` didn't look like JSON anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in your POST request:

You didn't specify a `Content-Type`. Notice the consequences as described in section [3.1.1.5 Content-Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) :

*If a Content-Type header field is not present, the recipient MAY either assume a media type of `application/octet-stream` ([RFC2046], Section 4.5.1) or examine the data to determine its type.*

That is, the server will likely assume the content is of type `application/octet-stream` which is not appropriate in your case. I would suggest `application/json`. Despite the fact that this would also require a change on the server - it's much easier to create and to process on the client and the server.

I would *not* recommend `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` since it requires encoding and its usage is much more error prone.

Furthermore, in your code you didn't correctly initialize the data object:

> `NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];

Parameter *length* should be set to the number of bytes of the string representation in UTF-8 - and NOT `[myRequestString length]` since this returns the number of characters (more precisely, the number UTF-16 code units).

As mentioned, you can avoid a couple of potential issues when using JSON as the underlying content type. You would first create a JSON representation as your "body". That is, you would create a `NSDictionary` with a key `@city` and whose value (type `NSString`) becomes `Label.text`. Then serialize this object to JSON using `NSJSONSerialization` into a `NSData` object which contains a UTF-8 JSON and which becomes your request body.